# ImageMagick. Multiple SVG files are only allowed for PDF and PS output

Tags: macos, bash

I'm running script `/tools/generatepngall.sh` from https://github.com/twain47/Open-SVG-Map-Icons to generate PNG icons from SVG-files.

However, there are errors:

```
Multiple SVG files are only allowed for PDF and PS output.
Multiple SVG files are only allowed for PDF and PS output.
convert: unable to open image `/Volumes/Data/Downloads/SJJB-SVG-Icons-20111021/pngall/accommodation_alpinehut.p.0092DA.32.png': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2643.
convert: unable to open file `/Volumes/Data/Downloads/SJJB-SVG-Icons-20111021/pngall/accommodation_alpinehut.p.0092DA.32.png' @ error/png.c/ReadPNGImage/3995.
convert: image sequence is required `+clone' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/946.
Multiple SVG files are only allowed for PDF and PS output.
Multiple SVG files are only allowed for PDF and PS output.
```

I can't understand what's wrong.

P.S.: I googled an answer, that it might be due to `rsvg` should have an `-o` before output filename, and I changed it in `recolourtopng.sh`, but the result is the same.

Comment: What arguments at passed to the script when you invoke it? Does the missing file in fact exist? Why does the script expect that exact file? (Is it input or an intermediary file that went missing or was not created due to another error?)

Comment: @bmike SVG files exists, script doesn't need an arguments, all the options(sizes and colours) specified at the beginning of it. PNG files do not exists, due to this error: ```Multiple SVG files are only allowed for PDF and PS output.```

Comment: @bmike This means, that ```rsvg``` thinks that it has a list of files, but actually it is one file. As I assume, this is problem line: ```${BASEFOLDER}/tools/recolour.sh $1 $2 $3 $4 | rsvg -f png -w ${5} -h ${5} /dev/stdin ${6}.png```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/dev/stdin was superfluous.

When I removed it, it works perfectly:

```
${BASEFOLDER}/tools/recolour.sh $1 $2 $3 $4 | rsvg -f png -w ${5} -h ${5} -o ${6}.png
```